# WTForms - POSTing text fields to an array

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

In regular HTML, you can have multiple fields POST to an array:

```
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
<input type="text" name="arr[]">
```

How can I get this functionality from WTForms? Basically, I have a form where users and click on little plus and minus buttons to add or remove fields from the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for WTForm [FieldList](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/fields/#wtforms.fields.FieldList). It allows you to create an arbitrary list of the same field.

Ex.

```
emails = FieldList(StringField('email'), min_entries=1, max_entries=5)
```

Comment: How would I add an extra 'email' field to the page via Javascript? edit: I guess what I'm asking is whether or not WTForms will know that I've added another field.

Comment: If you want to do it via javascript, you'll have to look at the code that's generated by wtforms and mimic that for each additional entry you want to add. WTForms will not know the difference if your new field matches what it expects. It should be able to process fields added this way.

Comment: Got it working, thanks! For future reference, when you do it this way, WTForms generates an input field with the name "email-0". When you add another one with Javascript, you need to increment that number on the end, so your next field will be named "email-1" and so on.